# Windows 10 - Does using extend displays incurs processing for the turned off screen?

Tags: windows-10, display, display-settings

Say I have two screens on Extend displays mode - PC monitor and TV.
When the TV is off is the other screen still being rendered? Does it incur processing power?
How about when it is on but on a different source?

I'm guessing it is but just making sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely if the screen's connection still registers as 'alive'. If it does, then your computer is still drawing to it, hence using processing power.

Your computer will probably also respond differently depending on whether the connection does stay live or not. A test would be to unplug the TV from mains power & see if the computer responds differently.

If you move a window to the extended display & it jumps back to the primary in either of the above circumstances, then the display is 'not live'.

Comment: Nowadays with smart TVs I don't think they're really off at any point. This means the GPU will always render that screen right?

Comment: Yes: hence the 'power it off' test - I mean literally unplug it, & see if the computer's reaction is different to it just being on standby. Most time, you actually **want** the connection to stay live, otherwise all your windows jump back to the primary & you have to set them all up again.